# Authenticating with oauth2 using package "golang.org/x/oauth2"

Tags: go, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to figure out how I can use the package `golang.org/x/oauth2` to authenticate on a site supporting oauth2.

The code I wrote below works, I am just curious if this is the right approach, using this particular library, to obtain an *http.Client:

```
func handleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    state := r.FormValue("state")
    if state != oauthStateString {
        fmt.Printf("invalid oauth state, expected '%s', got '%s'\n", oauthStateString, state)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    code := r.FormValue("code")
    token, err := oauthConf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("oauthConf.Exchange() failed with '%s'\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token.AccessToken},
    )

    tc := oauth2.NewClient(oauth2.NoContext, ts) // got *http.Client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up: I've used it and tweaked it several times and it does the job.